# How to open two sockets on client side using two different interface

Tags: c, sockets

I have to transfer the data through eth0 & eth1. So I have written a code in client side in which I am opening two sockets using thread.But its not working properly means it is not connecting eth1(connection error). Data is being sent through etho only.
Note: Here I am using two separate networks.
    This is my code.Please go through this...

```
void Socket_1()
{

    struct sockaddr_in ser_sock1 ;
    u_int yes=1 ;
    int setsock_fd ;
    ser_sock1.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    ser_sock1.sin_port = htons( 1602 ) ;
    ser_sock1.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("192.168.1.35")            
    cl_fd1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) ;
    if (cl_fd1 == -1) 
    {
        printf("Socket1 : ERROR\n") ;
        return ;
    }
    /* Bind to socket*/
    if( bind(cl_fd1,(struct sockaddr *)&ser_sock1 , sizeof(ser_sock1)) < 0)
    {
        printf("bind1 : ERROR\n") ;
        return ;
    }

    /* Construct the server sockaddr_in structure */
    memset(&ser_sock1, 0, sizeof(ser_sock1));       /* Clear struct */
    ser_sock1.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    ser_sock1.sin_port = htons( 22008 ) ;
    ser_sock1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.151") ;
    /*connect to destination*/
    con_fd1 = connect(cl_fd1, (struct sockaddr *)(&ser_sock1), sizeof(ser_sock1));
    if(con_fd1 < 0)
    {
        printf("connect1 : ERROR\n") ;
        while(1)
        {
        }
        return ;
    } 
    g_socketCreated = 1 ;
    while(g_socketCreated)
    {
        sprintf( buff, "Mess-%08X", count++ );
        send( cl_fd1, buff, strlen(buff), 0x0 ) ;
        sleep(1) ;
    }
}

void Socket_2(void)
{

    struct sockaddr_in ser_sock2, ser_sock3 ;   
    ser_sock2.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    ser_sock2.sin_port = 0 ;
    ser_sock2.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.42.130") ;
    cl_fd2 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) ;
    if (cl_fd2 == -1) 
    {
        printf("Socket2 : ERROR\n") ;
        return ;
    }
    /* Bind to socket*/
    if( bind(cl_fd2,(struct sockaddr *)&ser_sock2 , sizeof(ser_sock2)) < 0)
    {
        printf("bind2 : ERROR\n") ;
        return ;
    }

    /* Construct the server sockaddr_in structure */
    memset(&ser_sock3, 0, sizeof(ser_sock3));       /* Clear struct */
    ser_sock3.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    ser_sock3.sin_port = htons( 22000 ) ;
    ser_sock3.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("110.234.115.27") ;


    /*connect to destination*/
    con_fd2 = connect(cl_fd2, (struct sockaddr *)(&ser_sock3), sizeof(ser_sock3));
    if(con_fd2 < 0)
    {
        printf("connect2 : ERROR\n") ;
        return ;
    } 
    g_socketCreated1 = 1 ;
    while(1)
    {
        sprintf( buff1, "soc2---Mess-%08X", count1++ );
        send( cl_fd2, buff1, strlen(buff1), 0x0 ) ;
        sleep(1) ;
    }       
}
```

Comment: You have the `bind()` call commented out in `socket1`, is that intentional?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? You should use `perror()` when reporting errors so you see the error message.

Comment: Because you're using `SO_BINDTODEVICE` to override the routing table and manually control the interface of packet egress, a description of your network topology including a dump of `ip addr` and `ip route` on the host where you're trying to do this might be pertinent.

Comment: @Barmar,I have checked with bind also but still this error was.then I used SO_BINDTODEVICE.When I am using perror.It is showing "connect1: Connection refused".Actualywhen I am connecting both(eth0,usb0) then data is not sent but when I remove the eth0.then data is sent through usb0.so here i am stopped how to sent data using both.

Comment: "Connection refused" means that there's no server listening on the port you're trying to connect to, and doesn't have anything to do with which device you're using.

Comment: @Barmar,that is the problem getting here.so is there any ioctl call to bind to either socket or any other settings to OS is required..??

Comment: @Celada,Before using SO_BINDTODEVICE, I have simply used bind for both sockets. But it was also not working.So any ioctl call is there to bind to an specific ip address?

Comment: Binding to an IP address has nothing to do with fixing "Connection refused". You're connecting to the wrong destination address or port, or the server isn't running.

Comment: @Barmar,here I am passing my static ip & another system static ip in one socket. And in another socket,ip address of the other interface & public ip address of system i am passing.then it is showing connection refused.I have tried so many times with changes but I am not getting where is the exact mistake.

Comment: Connection refused means just one thing: There's nothing listening at the remote ip/port you tried to connect to, so maybe the mistake is on the server. There's one other possibility: a firewall blocking you.

Comment: @Barmar, I have disabled the firewall.but still this issue is.

Comment: > I am totally stopped here to this issue.And I am not getting what is >wrong.Is there any wrong in my code or it needs to change something >in OS settings.

Comment: What does `telnet 192.168.1.151 22008` do? If it also gets "Connection refused", then you need to check the server.

Comment: @Barmar, this ip address is of other system where server program is written.when etho cable is connected then data is not sent but when i remove the etho cable then the data is sent to that system(server program).

Comment: I know what it is, that's the whole point. That command will tell if there's really a server listening on that address/port. What does disconnecting the cable have to do with this question? There's nothing wrong with your code that I can see.

Comment: Sounds like a routing issue. Your Socket2 is connecting to an IP outside of it's subnet.  Which interface has a default GW set up on it?  If it's eth0, then that would be why.  +1 to @Celada for asking for the topology info.

Comment: @SteveLazaridis,I have used routing command also for my both ip address(one with eth0,2nd with usb0).